# How to prevent non-numeric input in C?

Tags: c

I wrote a small C program which will get an input from the user and check if the input is even or odd.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter an integer number: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    if(n%2 == 0)
    {
        printf("\n%d is an EVEN number.\n",n);
    }
    else
        printf("\n%d is an ODD number.\n",n);

     return 0;
}
```

but when I enter an alphabet or a symbol, it shows the output as 0 and says input is EVEN. How can I prevent user from entering alphabets and symbols? What's the easiest way to do that?

Comment: check `scanf()`s result; it should be 1 if it could scan a number and 0 elsewhere (and in that case , the value of `n` is undetermined)

Comment: You cannot stop the user entering garbage.  What you can do is detect that the user entered garbage and handle it correctly (which often involves refusing to use the garbage input and asking them to try again).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to check the return value of `scanf`.  From [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf):

> **Return Value**
>
> Number of receiving arguments successfully assigned, or `EOF` if read failure occurs before the first receiving argument was assigned.

Applied to your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main()
{
  int n;
  printf("Enter an integer number: ");
  if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1)
    {
      printf("This is not a number.\n");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
  else if (n % 2 == 0)
    {
      printf("\n%d is an EVEN number.\n", n);
      return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
  else
    {
      printf("\n%d is an ODD number.\n", n);
      return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you give input as combination of integer and character, then the program doesn't work as expected. Example: If I give input as 1a, the result says the number is odd.

Comment: @Vamsi It depends on what you expect.  The program above tries to read the first integer from the input and ignores everything after it.  This might or might not be what you need.  Personally, I wouldn't use `scanf` at all but read an entire line of input via `getline` and see if it is exactly one integer.  Well, no, I'd just use the command line arguments for this which would be the better design anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Simply check the return value of `scanf` - it'll tell you how many format objects were successfully parsed. In this case, it'll return 1 if it could parse an int, and 0 if it couldn't.

Comment: And if it can't and you want to process the data in a loop, you need to read past the bogus character(s) - possibly up to end of line.

Answer (score 3):

If the input **is** an integer, then `scanf()` will return `1` so you can check

```
if (scanf("%d", &integer) != 1)
    invalidInput();
```

to ask the user again you should know that there could be characters left in the `stdin` that need to be read so you can flush them with `getchar()` so a complete function would be

```
int scanint(const char *const message)
{
    int value;

    printf("%s > ", message);
    while (scanf("%d", &value) != 1)
    {
        int chr;
        printf("\tinvalid input...\n");
        do {
            chr = getchar();
        } while ((chr != EOF) && (chr != '\n'));
        printf("%s > ", message);
    }
    return value;
}
```

and you can use it like this

```
int main()
{
    int value = scanint("please input an integer");
    printf("your input was: %d\n", value);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can give you two approaches:

1. very easy — check for return value of `scanf()`. 1 indicates success (integer read) and 0 if any non-integer is put in there (or EOF on EOF).
2. by writing code for it:

   ```
   #include <ctype.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   int isNumeric (const char * s)
   {
       if (s == NULL || *s == '\0' || isspace(*s))
           return 0;
       char * p;
       strtod (s, &p);
       return *p == '\0';
   }
   ```

   Now in this case your `scanf` has to take a string from user and then pass that string to the function `isNumeric()`.

Comment: Using `strtod()` is interesting; it looks for 'real' numbers.  You could use `strtol()` or a relative for integers (with the possibility of using 0 as the base so that 0xAA and 0377 would be recognized as hex and octal respectively.

Comment: yaa @JonathanLeffler using strtol() can be a better implementation for this.