# C, add statement to check if input is an integer

Tags: c, if-statement

This is currently what I have, I want to add a statement at the bottom that prints `printf("Error");` if the data entered isn't a number.

```
int main() {
    long long number;
    long long ret;
    
    printf("Enter a number between [0 - 4294967295]: ");
    scanf("%lld", &number);
    
    printf("Number is %lld\n", number);
    //if statements to see if number is above/below the range
    if (number < 0) {
        printf("Error: This number is below the range.");
        return -1;
    }
    if (number > 4294967295) {
        printf("Error: This number is above the range.");
        return -1;
    } 
    //this is where I would like to add the statement
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check the return value of your `scanf` call. It will tell you how many fields it converted. You will not be able to tell if there was other user input using `scanf` the way you are using it. You read an input line into a buffer and then scan it for anything that isn't a numeric character.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent non-numeric input in C & ask user input again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65043036/how-to-prevent-non-numeric-input-in-c-ask-user-input-again)

Comment: Please check the following thread
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17292545/how-to-check-if-the-input-is-a-number-or-not-in-c

Comment: Does my answer suit your question? If so, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

***NOTE:*** User jwdonahue pointed a [better solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65043036/how-to-prevent-non-numeric-input-in-c-ask-user-input-again) using `fgets()`/`sscan()` instead.

---

According to the manual page of **`scanf`**:

> On  success,  these functions return the **number of input items successfully matched and assigned**; this can be fewer  than  provided  for,  or even zero, in the event of an early matching failure.

Since you have one value to read, you retrieve the return value of `scanf()` first and check it before checking `number` value:

```
int read_items;
read_items = scanf("%lld", &number);
if (read_items == 0) {
  printf("Not a number\n");
  return 1; // exit with an error status (!= 0)
}
```

Also you should check *before that* if even one value was read, which is described by the manual page:

> The  value **`EOF`** is **returned** if the **end of input** is **reached before** either the **first successful** conversion **or a matching failure** occurs. EOF is also returned if a **read error occurs**

Hence:

```
int read_items;
read_items = scanf("%lld", &number);
if (read_items == EOF) {
  printf("No value entered or error occured\n");
  return 1; // exit with an error status (!= 0)
}
if (read_items == 0) {
  printf("Not a number\n");
  return 1; // exit with an error status (!= 0)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for (i=0;i<length; i++)
        if (!isdigit(input[i]))
        {
            printf ("Entered input is not a number\n");
            exit(1);
        }
```

`isdigit(c)` is a function in C which can be used to check if the passed character is a digit or not. It returns a non-zero value if it’s a digit else it `returns 0`

Comment: It does not cover all the cases. For example: `-10`. By the way OP retrieved an integer, not a string (`char*`).

Comment: This answer is incomplete and unlikely to be useful to a beginner, who would be asking this type of question. See @amessihel's answer above for an example of a good answer.

Comment: Hmm... this looks like it was ripped from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17292545/how-to-check-if-the-input-is-a-number-or-not-in-c